# Android Studio Action Bar logo display

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am trying to display a permanent small logo on the left size of the `ActionBar`, but I can't find how to do so. Please help me find a solution.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.redislabs.app.redis.infoIntent">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a place to Specify your [Logo](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#logo) in the

```
<application>
```

tag. This is located in your Manifest.xml file for your app. The value should be set to locate a drawable resource.

```
<application
  android:logo="drawable resource">
```

I hope this helps!

Happy Coding! Leave a comment if you have any questions.

Comment: To clarify, this is different from your app's specified icon.

Comment: tried, didnt work. maybe there is somthing blocking it? i do have a layoutdrawer.

Comment: Are you sure that the place you are looking to display this logo is the ActionBar?

Comment: pretty sure.
let me give you an example,
if you open up whatsapp, and enter a private chat with your friend(not a group) and you can see his/hers profile picture.
so instead of a profile picture i want my icon (ofcurse as extended to the drawer, but it may be a substituted for the drawer icon).